# Grails namedQueries in Hierarchies

Tags: grails, groovy

It seems to me that defining

```
static namedQueries = {}
```

in a subclass of a  hierarchy masks completely the super class's namedQueries declaration. Is there a way to get both working? Say using a super key word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Groovy 1.8 was added closure composition, which should allow you to do this via a left shift operator.

```
static namedQueries = SuperClass.namedQueries << {
    myAdditionalQuery {
        ...
    }
}
```

But that won't be available until Grails 2.0, as Grails 1.3.7 uses Groovy 1.7.